# Dealing with excel files in Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have a folder with .xlsx files in and I need sum every three files together and output the result into a new .xlsx file using Python. There are over one hundred files. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) in order to read the data and [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) in order to create a new excel file.

If you write some python code of what you have already tried and doesn't work we might be able to help a bit.

Comment: I have tried to add the data in the files to a data frame, add the data frames  to a list and then call the files from the list I need and then add the data frames together and write an excel file but I am only getting the last data frame that the code read in as the output. Sorry I haven't got access to the code at the moment